# How to concatenate lines by unix commands

Tags: regex, unix

I have next file myfile.txt

```
"field1","val1","val2","val3"
"field2","val1","val2","val3"
"field3","val1","va
  l2","va
  l3"
"field4","val1","val2","val3"
```

I want to do this file in normal view like that:

```
"field1","val1","val2","val3"
"field2","val1","val2","val3"
"field3","val1","val2","val3"
"field4","val1","val2","val3"
```

So, I am trying to do that with next commands:

```
filename=myfile.txt

while read line
do
   found=$(grep '^[^"]')
   if [ "$found" ]; then          
      #think here must be command "paste"      
   fi   
done < $filename
```

but something wrong. Please help me, I am not guru in unix commands

Comment: Don't put `//` delimiters around the regexp in `grep`.

Comment: `awk` would be a better method for this. If the line doesn't end with `"`, read the next line and concatenate it.

Comment: @Barmar edited unix commands, but now I am finding just 1 row

Comment: You're not passing any input to `grep`, so it's reading from the rest of the file.

Comment: You should be testing the *end* of the line, not the beginning. If it ends with `"` echo it with a newline after. If it doesn't, echo it with no newline.

Comment: `found=$(grep '"$' <<<"$line")`

Comment: @Barmar in my case works perfect this one: found=$(grep '^[^"]' <<<"$line")

Comment: @Barmar but how to concatenate now ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
filename=$1

while read -r line
do
   found=$found$(echo $line | grep '[^"]')
   if [[ -n $found && $found == *\" ]]; then
       echo $found;
       found=''
   fi
done < "$filename"
```

1. The variable `$found` is always appended to itself this way you'll join the "broken lines".
2. In the if it's then checked if `$found` is not empty (`-n` does just that) and then check if `$found` ends with a quote as suggested by @Barmar

If it does end with a quote that's the end so you `echo $found` set variable to empty

Comment: Thanks, but now is problem how to concatenate?

Comment: Quote your variables.

Comment: @AndreyKhmelev The line that begins with `found=` concatenates.

Comment: You don't need to check if it's not empty. If it's empty it won't match the pattern.

Comment: @AndreyKhmelev Make sure there's a newline at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

***sed*** solution:

```
sed -Ez 's/[[:space:]]+//g; s/""/","/g; s/(([^,]+,){3})([^,]+),/\1\3\n/g; $a\\' myfile.txt
```

- `-z` - treat the input as lines separated by null(zero) character instead of newlines
- `s/[[:space:]]+//g` - remove whitespaces between/within lines
- `s/""/","/g` - separating adjacent fields which were wrapped/breaked
- `s/(([^,]+,){3})([^,]+),/\1\3\n/g` - set linebreak (record separator) on each 4th field
- `$a\\` - append the final newline at the end of the content

---

The output:

```
"field1","val1","val2","val3"
"field2","val1","val2","val3"
"field3","val1","val2","val3"
"field4","val1","val2","val3"
```

Comment: @anvitasurapaneni, see my explanation

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing number of fields in input, you can use this gnu-awk solution using `FPAT` and `gensub`:

```
awk -v RS= -v FPAT='("[^"]*"|[^,"]+),?' -v OFS= '{
      for (h=1; h<=NF; h++) $h = gensub(/([^"])\n[[:blank:]]*/, "\\1", "g", $h); } 1' file

"field1","val1","val2","val3"
"field2","val1","val2","val3"
"field3","val1","val2","val3"
"field4","val1","val2","val3"
```

To save changes back to file use:

```
awk -i inplace -v RS= -v FPAT='("[^"]*"|[^,"]+),?' -v OFS= '{
       for (h=1; h<=NF; h++) $h = gensub(/([^"])\n[[:blank:]]*/, "\\1", "g", $h); } 1' file
```